# Can Moq return the real object instance passed into a Setup method called on a Mock with a void return type?

Tags: c#, moq

I have a call as such:

```
_session.Setup(session => session.SaveOrUpdate(It.IsAny<Foo>()))
```

I want to retrieve a copy of whatever instance of `Foo` is passed into `SaveOrUpdate` when the test is run for validation.  How can I get a copy of that exact `Foo` into my test?

I tried to use `.Callback`, but maybe that is not the way to do this?  Or maybe I'm doing it wrong... not sure, but I could use some assistance trying to figure out if this is possible and how to do this please.

```
Foo foo;

_session.Setup(session => session.SaveOrUpdate(It.IsAny<Foo>()))
        .Callback<Foo>(fooInstanceBeingSaved => foo = fooInstanceBeingSaved as Foo);
```

In this scenario, `foo` is always returned `null`, even though the real `foo` in the service layer is populated.

EDIT:
This is not a duplicate of said duplicate because this question differs in that SaveOrUpdate returns void.  In the reportedly duplicate articles, those methods return something other than void.  As such, I need to get the variable out of a method where "Returns" is not a valid option - which is the solution in the other articles.

Comment: It looks OK. Are you certain that `foo` is null because the callback isn't being called? Or is it because `as` is returning `null`? Can you put a breakpoint in the callback lambda to check?

Comment: Yes, foo is coming back null.  Even if I leave it as an object without any casting/"as".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Channeling some psychic powers here...*

It looks like you may be using [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/), which if so that means `SaveOrUpdate` has this signature:

```
void SaveOrUpdate(object obj);
```

So, in order to get your `Foo` object you need to specify `object` as the type parameter, e.g.:

```
_session.Setup(session => session.SaveOrUpdate(It.IsAny<object>()))
        .Callback<object>(objectBeingSaved => foo = objectBeingSaved as Foo);
```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought to change IsAny<Foo> to IsAny<object> before.  This works now.  Thanks!